# Get waypoint position

Tags: lua, fivem

I am creating my first lua script for fivem what I am trying to do is get the waypoint postition in 1 function and then echo the position in chat and eventualy teleport to it. However I can't even use the command /tpw in the chat it just says it doesn't exist. Please give me some pointers. Also should I use ; after defining variables etc?

```
RegisterCommand("tpw", teleportToPoint(), false)

function teleportToPoint()
    TriggerEvent("chatMessage", "[Server]", {255, 0, 0}, waypoint)
end

function getWaypoint()
    local waypoint = getWaypoint
    return waypoint
end
```

Comment: `var` is not a lua keyword, you maybe getting an error trying to load it. not really familiar with fivem.

Comment: Yep, changed it to local. Now I just need to figure out how to get the coordinates of the waypoint. Thanks tho @Nifim